# Using jquery to capture click event on <li> element not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On this page:
http://www.jwallacellc.com/fabric.htm

If you click any of the numbered blocks on a computer, a pop-up appears.

If you click them on an iPad, the hover state appears, then clicking a second time makes the pop-up appear.

I want the pop-up to appear on the first click on iPad.

Curiously, almost the exact same thing happens on this website's home page, but in that case the first click opens the pop-up without a problem:
http://www.jwallacellc.com

I don't understand why they are reacting differently. In both cases, the hover state is handled by CSS:

```
ul#home li:hover h2{height:160px;}
ul.interior li:hover h2{display:block;}
```

The clicks are handled by jQuery/Javascript:

```
$('#home li').click(function(){…});
$('ul.interior li').click(function(){…});
```

Is there some difference in my selectors that is causing iPad to not capture the click event the first time, on my interior page, but not the home page? Does iPad think because there is a hover state, it should show that the first time? But why would Javascript ignore the click event in that case? And in any event, my two pages are functioning differently for some reason.

Would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

iOS require an `href="#"` parameter on links

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is just one of the differences between desktop and iPad web development.  The iPad is listening for touch events, but can still handle click events (somewhat).  The first touch is always a hover and the second a click, when you're listening for clicks.

You can get around this by listening for touch events using something like [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) instead of jQuery, or a jQuery plugin for touch events, instead of listening to click events.

Or if you like, you can manually setup touch events with [a tutorial like this.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/)

I'm not sure why one of the pages actually works on the first touch, I've never been able to accomplish that with a click handler.

Comment: That makes sense. I added a "touchend" event to my script, now both screens indeed pick up when you touch the element. I still don't understand why the home page doesn't require this, though, as they are nearly identical. Also, if I touch my iPad to drag/scroll the screen with my finger over one of the elements, the "touchend" event is triggered, opening the pop-up unintentionally.